# getting error when i run flutter app in android studio

Tags: flutter

Building without sound null safety
For more information see https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety

Expected elements are <{}codename>,<{}layoutlib>,<{}api-level>
/C:/Users/Manoj/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/modal_bottom_sheet-2.0.0/lib/src/bottom_sheet.dart:303:28: Error: Couldn't find constructor 'VelocityTracker'.
_velocityTracker = VelocityTracker();
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/Manoj/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_typeahead-3.2.4/lib/src/flutter_typeahead.dart:754:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.

- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  WidgetsBinding.instance!.removeObserver(this);
  ^
  /C:/Users/Manoj/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_typeahead-3.2.4/lib/src/flutter_typeahead.dart:767:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  WidgetsBinding.instance!.addObserver(this);
  ^
  /C:/Users/Manoj/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_typeahead-3.2.4/lib/src/flutter_typeahead.dart:801:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((duration) {
  ^
  /C:/Users/Manoj/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_typeahead-3.2.4/lib/src/flutter_typeahead.dart:936:9: Error: No named parameter with the name 'maxLengthEnforced'.
  maxLengthEnforced: widget.textFieldConfiguration.maxLengthEnforced,
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_field.dart:276:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  const TextField({
  ^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/Users/Manoj/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_typeahead-3.2.4/lib/src/cupertino_flutter_typeahead.dart:558:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  WidgetsBinding.instance!.removeObserver(this);
  ^
  /C:/Users/Manoj/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_typeahead-3.2.4/lib/src/cupertino_flutter_typeahead.dart:571:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  WidgetsBinding.instance!.addObserver(this);
  ^
  /C:/Users/Manoj/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_typeahead-3.2.4/lib/src/cupertino_flutter_typeahead.dart:605:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((duration) {
  ^
  /C:/Users/Manoj/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_typeahead-3.2.4/lib/src/cupertino_flutter_typeahead.dart:746:9: Error: No named parameter with the name 'maxLengthEnforced'.
  maxLengthEnforced: widget.textFieldConfiguration.maxLengthEnforced,
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/text_field.dart:209:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  const CupertinoTextField({
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1156
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.

> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 27s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           88.7s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
The terminal process "C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat 'build', 'apk'" terminated with exit code: 1.

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

this happened to me after I updated flutter version , if you used modal bottom sheet package then just set or update to this version `modal_bottom_sheet: ^2.0.1` in `pubspec`
and run `pub get`

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72212023/flutter-operand-of-null-aware-operation-has-type-widgetsbinding-which-ex/72255021#72255021)

the Packages you use arent updated to Flutter 3.0 yet.